# What do results like Z = [_G305] mean in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I've got these definitions:

```
memberx(X, [X|_]).
memberx(X, [_|T]) :- memberx(X, T).

intersectionx([], _, []).
intersectionx([H|T], Y, [_|Z]) :- memberx(H, Y), !, intersectionx(T, Y, Z).
intersectionx([_|T], Y, Z) :- intersectionx(T, Y, Z).
```

I get the following result:

```
?- intersectionx([1], [1], Z).
Z = [_G305].
```

Why doesn't it result in Z = [1]??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Z = [_G305].

means that this answer is true for all terms. That is, it is not
only true for Z = [1] - as you expect, but it is also true for Z = [2].

Clearly, that is not what you expected.

So where is the error? A simple way to detect it is to watch out for anonymous
variables denoted _.

Consider:

```
intersectionx([H|T], Y, [_|Z]) :- memberx(H, Y), !, intersectionx(T, Y, Z).
                        ^^^
```

What you have written means that the intersection of a list starting with
H and another list will be (provided the goals on the right hand side
are all true) a list starting with anything... Replace anything by that H!

Comment: Thanks, that was killing me. I should have noticed that the second definition was the problem since the base case was working fine :)  Thanks again!